# How to redirect WooCommerce product's checkout page from a specific user role

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have three user roles General users, pro users and Ultra pro users

i have categorized the product in general, pro and ultra product

now want to redirect on specific page accordingly

**general user** cannot see checkout page for pro and ultra products 
**pro** wont see checkout page for ultra pro
**ultra pro** can buy anything

```
add_action( 'wp', 'hide_product_from_specific_role' );
function hide_product_from_specific_role() {
  if ( is_product() ) {
    $product_id = get_the_ID();
    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    if ( in_array( 'specific_role', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
      wp_redirect( home_url() );
      exit;
    }
  }
}
```

how can i use this code if this is incorrect, what should be the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see what you are looking for, I had a similar project and I think that your code is missing an if statment to check if the user logged in and I think you beeter leave a msg to explain why the user cant access instade of sending him to homepage, so the code will be like that:

```
add_action( 'wp', 'hide_product_from_specific_role' );
function hide_product_from_specific_role() {
  if ( is_product() ) {
$product_id = get_the_ID();  
 if ( is_user_logged_in() && !current_user_can( 'specific_role' ) ) {
      wp_die( 'This product is not available to users with your role.' );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I can see any use of `$product_id` in your code. `$product_id` is also not being used in OP question, OP is also asking for redirect, but your code doesn't redirect, it brings the `Die` page. Please don't rush for answer and first get the enough information from OP then write the correct answe.